# Modify page supports in wordpress programmatically

Tags: wordpress, wordpress-theming

I want modify create/edit page from post type page to contain only title and custom-fields.

So after googling a bit im tryign to do this with this filter:

```
add_filter('register_post_type_args', 'override_pages', 10, 2); 

function override_pages($args, $post_type){

  if ($post_type == 'page'){
    $args['supports'] = array('title', 'custom-fields');
  }

return $args;

}
```

But it doesnt work

Do you know if it is possible?

**Edited**

I found the solution, this is:

```
function override_page_support() {
  remove_post_type_support( 'page', 'editor' );
  remove_post_type_support( 'page', 'revisions' );
  remove_post_type_support( 'page', 'page-attributes' );
  add_post_type_support( 'page', 'custom-fields' );
}
add_action( 'init', 'override_page_support' );
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use this code:

```
function override_page_support() {

    remove_post_type_support( 'page', 'editor' );
    remove_post_type_support( 'page', 'author' );
    remove_post_type_support( 'page', 'comments' );
    remove_post_type_support( 'page', 'thumbnail' );
    remove_post_type_support( 'page', 'excerpt' );
    remove_post_type_support( 'page', 'page-attributes' );
    remove_post_type_support( 'page', 'post-formats' );
    remove_post_type_support( 'page', 'revisions' );

}
add_action( 'init', 'override_page_support' );
```

---

- `title` (page title)
- `editor` (content)
- `author`
- `thumbnail` (featured image)
- `excerpt`
- `trackbacks`
- `custom-fields`
- `comments` (also will see comment count balloon on edit screen)
- `revisions` (will store revisions)
- `page-attributes` (template and menu order) (hierarchical must be true)
- `post-formats`

**Note:** You should use as per your requirement instead of all code.